# node.js vs java - compute intensive computation

Tags: java, node.js, performance, neural-network

I'm currently evaluating a backend architecture for an api, taking deeper looks into node.js and j2ee application server with corresponding j2ee war files. The api will have to compute quite cpu-intensive tasks - to be more specific the training of neural networks. Do you have any experience with such a setup concerning performance and/or packages one should use for machine learning? Are there any other API technologies I should consider - as for example java micro services?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Philipp

Comment: This really sounds like a request for opinions to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend at least two micro services. One for accepting API requests. The other(s) is for computation. You can choose any languages for these two.

For example:

1. A node.js API service - receives HTTP Restful requests. The service calls second service using a transactional RPC protocol like [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode#dnode-in-other-languages).
2. A stateless C++/Java/Go service - receives computation tasks via dnode RPC, performs calculations, and returns the result back.

As a result, you'll have offloaded frontend service. It will not lag on the high load. The second service is written using CPU optimized library/language. Moreover, you can scale the second service in case of very high load.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem and solved it by doing heavy computations in R child processes. I wrote a simple npm module you could try right now:

```
npm install computer
```

Now in your node application:

```
var computer  = require('computer');
var R = new computer('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/bin/x64/R.exe');

R.start(function(){
  R.run('cat("1 + 2 =", 1 + 2)', function(err, log){
    console.log(log);
    R.stop();
  });
});
```

This allows your single-threaded nodejs app to stay lean and mean while off-loading computations to a child process. I even connect to the database in R itself, so this a really powerful and efficient way of doing heay computations in node.

Answer (score 0):

Take your decision based on problem
Is the task CPU intensive or I/O bound?”
Some examples for CPU intensive operations are graphics or video editing or anything that require huge computational power. Some examples of I/O bound operations are real-time chat, media streaming, file processing, etc